# Php Explode string and out put each string without showing array

Tags: php

I have something saved in my database like this

```
 PHP,HTML,CSS,SQL,JQUERY,....
```

More can stile show or it might end up being 2 or 1 depending on how may saved for current viewing post.

Now i need to Output each string separately see below example

```
echo $str1; Output = PHP,

echo $str2; Output = HTML,

echo $str3; Output = CSS,

echo $str4; Output = JQUERY,
```

I tried using this but i don't understand what is showing me please i need help with it

Here is my code

```
<?php
$str = 'one,two,three,four';

print_r(explode(',',$str,0));

print_r(explode(',',$str,2));

print_r(explode(',',$str,-1));
?>
```

And the out put is this, is not what i want

```
Array ( [0] => one,two,three,four )
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two,three,four )
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two [2] => three )
```

Comment: uh, why not just have `$arr = explode(',', $str)`? The default for `explode` is to explode on ALL matching elements. you only specify the 3rd argument if you want LESS than than 'all'.

Comment: Why not just echo the indexes? You also might consider http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php, rather than explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array!

```
<?php
$str = 'one,two,three,four';

$array= explode(',',$str);

//Print each array element 
//('one' 'two' 'three' 'four' an so on...)
foreach($array as $element){
    echo $element;
}
?>
```

Comment: This answer is too simple

Comment: This answer does not solve the has more or can be 1 or 2. You will receive either not all of your results or an out of index errors. You should be looping. Not even saying my answer although I have not tested it @miglio answer looks to be the best.

Comment: @nerdlyist yup, i know. I just give him a way to know array. miglio answer is the best answer to fit his question

Answer (score 4):

maybe try this:

```
$str = 'one,two,three,four'; 
$newstr = explode(',',$str);

$n = 'str'; //sufix
$c=1; //counter
foreach($newstr as $value){
    $nn = $n.$c; //assign vars
    $$nn = $value; //assign value for var
    $c++;
}

var_dump($str1);
var_dump($str2);
var_dump($str3);
var_dump($str4);
```

response:

```
string 'one' (length=3)    
string 'two' (length=3)    
string 'three' (length=5)  
string 'four' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct explode creates an array and you need to loop the elements. (you also do not really need the max int.)

```
<?php
$str = 'one,two,three,four';
$arr = explode(',',$str);
foreach($arr as $elem){
    echo $elem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help I think

```
// Example
$str = 'one,two,three,four';
$pieces = explode(',', $str);
echo $pieces[0]; // one
echo $pieces[1]; // two
echo $pieces[2]; // three
echo $pieces[3]; // four

//Example 2
$str = 'one,two,three,four';
list($one, $two, $three, $four) = explode(',', $str);
echo $one; // one
echo $two; // two
echo $three; // three
echo $four; // four
```

More info [Explode PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)